# Unboxing Integer[] in AsyncTask

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-asynctask, autoboxing, unboxing

I am trying to populate several TextViews with data from AWS using an AsyncTask. In order to the load the data from AWS, I must submit a range-key value which is an int. AsyncTask will only allow you to send Integers as parameters.

Problem: How can I unbox the Integer parameters as int so that I can send the primitive int to AWS (during doInBackground) and grab the data?

(slots is the variable which identifies the data i want to grab for the view)

Code:
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

```
    class LoadPost extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Post> {
        @Override
        protected Post doInBackground(Integer... slots) {

            int i = (int) slots; <=this does not work

            Post post = AmazonCredentials.getInstance().mapper.load(Post.class, userID, slots);
            return post;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Post post) {
            int slotNumber = post.getSlotNumber();

            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("slot"+slotNumber, "id", "package name goes here");

            TextView slot = (TextView) view.findViewById(resID);
            slot.setText(post.getContent());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well from my knowlege slots is already an integer type, you would just need to reference the correct index of the integer you need, like 
`int i = slots[0];`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response- I just didn't fully understand how AsyncTask works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no *unboxing* needed. Refer to [Arbitrary Number of Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs) to see that when you say that an argument is of type `Integer...` what you're actually working with inside the method is `Integer[]` even if we just pass one single item it will be inside an array, so you can just do:

```
slots[0]; //3 or whatever integer
```

We don't need to do anything else, due to [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) which takes care of as the name suggests boxing and un-boxing primitive values in the corresponding object and vice-versa